# Как получить индексы из коллекции List<T>

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно получить индексы одного `list<T>`
Знаю что есть метод `IndexOf` но он не работает(не выводит индексы)
Для начала я создаю новый `List<T>` и переписываю в него значения старого,далее в цикле `for` я уже прохожу и беру из каждого элемента `List<T>` его индекс.
Но на практике вышло совершенно другое

```
List<double> arrY = new List<double>();//1-ый лист
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    arrY.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value));

List<double> indY = new List<double>();//Создаю для копирования и взятие индексов

indY.AddRange(arrY);//Для начала записываю все элементы листа

//Здесь я предполагаю что пройдусь циклом и соберу все индексы и сразу выведу их в datagridView
for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
{
    indY.IndexOf(indY[j],0);//читаю с 1-ой позиции
    dataGridView1[3, j].Value = indY[j];
}
```

Цикл перебора не помог,результат аналогичен,выводятся числа но не их индексы.

Comment: `indY.IndexOf(indY,0);` - компилируется?

Comment: @Igor исправил(не дописал),на самом деле indY[j]

Comment: а в чем смысл искать `indY.IndexOf(indY[j])`? если можно просто `j` использовать сразу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int index = indY.IndexOf(indY[j]);
dataGridView1[3, j].Value = index;
```